# Machine Learning for Dummies - Need help/pointers on where to start

Tags: python, machine-learning

I want to create a system that detects the type of image based on the color composition.

E.G =

Object A = Blue, Red, Orange, Green. 
Object B = Red, Green, Blue, Black.

Whenever i scan an image with a color composition of Blue-red- Orange- Green, the answer will be Object A.

I scanned a couple of tuts but i can't grasp it. I want to ask on what algo to use, and where do i start.

So far, what i've found that will help me with my problem is the K-Nearest Neighbor Algo, but i'm still looking for a more options. Any help will do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to me as a classification problem. You have objects with features (color composition) and want to classify them into classes A or B.

K-Nearest Neighbors is a good starting point. A perceptron (a simple neural network) would be another simple algorithm to try out, as well as the linear discriminant analysis.

If it turns out that your data are too complex for linear-separating algorithms, you can try a multi-layer perceptron, support vector machines, or random forests. There are also many other possibilities, but one of the above should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna try to read about the things you mentioned above. Kudos!